# I am working on display toast message when Wi-Fi turned on/off, I am getting error as below

Tags: android

I am working on display toast message when WI-Fi turned on/off, I am getting error as below:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.pmap.wifitoast, PID: 29538
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.pmap.wifitoast/com.example.pmap.wifitoast.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.pmap.wifitoast.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2250)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.pmap.wifitoast.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1089)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2240)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Comment: post your Jave code

Comment: please post your MainActivity code

Comment: Please post code where your logic of `WI-Fi turned on/off` placed

Comment: @kavya check updated code

Comment: Please post the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is a problem of your Intent.

Please add your Activity in your AndroidManifest.xml.

When you want to make a new activity, you should register it in your AndroidManifest.xml

There is another way to get an java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo exception and that is the activity that you are trying to start is abstract.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Seems you may be passing the Application `Context` not the `Activity Context` on your Java code.
Wherever you are passing it pass `this` or `ActivityName.this` instead.

Since use `getApplicationContext()` or `Activity_name.this`.

you get this exception because you can't cast the Application to `Activity` since Application is not a sub-class of `Activity`.

Comment: I am already Added Activity in AndroidManifest.xml but i am getting error